# Change backcolor of array elements in loop

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops, colors, tostring

I am trying to change the background color of my labels which are stored into an array using loop, here is my array

```
Dim Setlab(3) as String
Setlab(0) = Label1.Text
SetLab(1) = Label2.Text
SetLab(2) = Label3.Text
SetLab(3) = Label4.Text
```

and here is my loop

```
Dim bcolor As Object
bcolor = Color.Aqua
For i = 0 To Setlab.Length - 1 
    SetLab(i) = bcolor.ToString          
Next
Dim display As String = String.Join(",",SetLab)              
Label2.Text = "A = {" & display & "}"
```

but the output was of my label was Color[Aqua], when I tried
`Setlab(i) = bcolor` only it errors with `bcolor conversion from color to string is not valid`. Can you help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand the error message? There is nothing more to say...

Comment: hello @muffi yes, still I tried  different ways. But what i'm trying to is find a way to do it in a loop still.

Comment: Your array contains nothing but text. Text has no inherent background colour.  If what you're trying to accomplish is to set the `BackColor` of each `Label` then you would need an array containing the `Labels`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thank you for pointing it, i understood it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim Setlab(3) as Label
Setlab(0) = Label1
SetLab(1) = Label2
SetLab(2) = Label3
SetLab(3) = Label4
```

Then your loop should be like this

```
Dim bcolor As Color
bcolor = Color.Aqua
For i = 0 To Setlab.Length - 1 
    SetLab(i).BackColor = bcolor
Next
```

Comment: hello @preciousbetine, thank you for this it worked. I'm new to vb, thank you for your help.